# What is the maximum records I should fetch from a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

My server is running slow as I am trying to fetch 200 records from a MySQl database (using PHP).  They are posts that I need to display and I know this is my error because when I try to fetch 1 record it is fast, 200 slows it down tremendously.

Is this a known problem, fetching for too many entries causes a problem?

Comment: I'd say the problem is likely with your SQL query, not with the DBMS itself. Without seeing the query, not much else to be said.

Comment: Have you considered that your SQL code runs slowly, despite the final rowcount?

Comment: It only depends on the way you fetch. It's usual to fetch thousands of records without any problem, even in PHP (just don't put them in memory at once).

Comment: If you are rendering the resultset to the PHP page, this could be where your problem is and not actually the MySQL.

Comment: You guys seem to be right, I just tried deleting everything besides the function calling the array, and it loads very fast.  The problem seems to be after the data is fetched.  Thanks!

Comment: It should be noted, that the default behavior of many DB extensions is to buffer the entire result in memory. The deprecated `mysql_query` buffers the result, `mysql_unbuffered_query` is needed to avoid that; `mysqli_query` by default calls `mysqli_store_result` and needs a `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` result mode passed explicitly to avoid buffering. `PDO` seems to operate with unbuffered results by default.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code must be a complicated function looping every time for each record. So it should be running 200 times.. That will slow the page response time. Fetching 200 records in MYSQL is not problem at all. It will run instantly if you run in MySql Terminal..

Comment: More of a comment than an answer

Answer (score 1):

There are three possibilities that might slow you server down from your side.

1. Your database is not optimized. Optimizing your database can give you a tremendous performance increase
2. Your query is doing something wrong. We need to see what query you are running to get the 200 rows.
3. You are running an individual query for each row in a loop.

What i would suggest though is base your query on this eg.

SELECT fields FROM table WHERE condition = required condition LIMIT 200

Also if that query runs slowly then do an explain to see what indexing its using

EXPLAIN SELECT fields FROM table WHERE condition = required condition LIMIT 200

Because to get 200 rows should take milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Number of records you can store in your table, that number of records you can fetch.

```
for unsigned int largest value is 4,294,967,295
for unsigned big int largest value is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615
```

for access records fast you need to define LIMIT in query.

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch the records needed for displaying, no more no less. Do not fetch records for (simple) calculations, as that can be done in the query.

I would say that displaying 50 ~ 100 records is the max a users brain can scan, getting all the info in the records.

I am an exception, when seeing more then 15 records, my brain tilts :)